# How to perform this kind of CURL request on Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, curl, digest, digest-authentication

I am using an API provided by my web host with whom I can register new clients and domains. Unfortunately they don't provide much documentation (basically none) and I'm not very used to cURL

They give ONE and very superficial example of how to create a new client, and it is as follows

`curl -d "clienteTipo=I&clienteCPFCNPJ=00112135045&clienteEmpresa=NomeEmpresa&clienteNome=meunome&clienteEmail=email@dominio.com.br&clienteEmailCobranca=emailcobranca@dominio.com.br&clienteSenhaPainel=654321&clienteFone=555100000000&clienteFax=555100000001&clienteCEP=44587421&clienteEndereco=ruanome&clienteBairro=meubairro&clienteCidade=porto alegre&clienteEstado=rs&clienteLimiteMapeamento=1&clienteLimiteSubdominio=2&clienteLimiteMysql=3&clienteLimiteMssql=1&clienteLimitePgsql=1&clienteLimiteFirebird=1&clienteLimiteFTPADD=1&clienteUniBox=on&clienteAcessoFTP=on&clienteAcessoDownloadBackup=on" -k --digest -u usuario:senha -X POST https://api.kinghost.net/cliente`

How can I transform this on a cURL request on Ruby keeping the parameters as informed above?

This must be a POST, but I wonder how I have to inform these parameters, they look like a query string. And what is this Digest thing?

Comment: http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after struggling for a while and testing different libraries, I used Ruby to run a system command, since cURL is not dependant on Ruby

```
output = `curl -d "clienteTipo=#{client_type}&clienteCPFCNPJ=#{client_id}&clienteEmpresa=#{company_name}&clienteNome=#{client_name}&clienteEmail=#{client_email}&clienteEmailCobranca=#{client_billing_email}&clienteSenhaPainel=#{password}&clienteFone=#{client_phone}&clienteFax=#{client_fax}&clienteCEP=#{client_zip_code}&clienteEndereco=#{client_address}&clienteBairro=#{client_neighborhood}&clienteCidade=#{client_city}&clienteEstado=#{client_state}&clienteLimiteMapeamento=1&clienteLimiteSubdominio=1&clienteLimiteMysql=1&clienteLimiteMssql=1&clienteLimitePgsql=1&clienteLimiteFirebird=1&clienteLimiteFTPADD=1&clienteUniBox=on&clienteAcessoFTP=on&clienteAcessoDownloadBackup=on" -k --digest -u MY_USER:MY_PASSWORD -X POST API_URL`

p output
xml = Hash.from_xml(output) #in my case it returns a XML string
```

Now output contains the response

Comment: Sometimes the simplest is the best! Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an (untested) example using rest-client that might get you started https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client).

According to what I was able to find online, rest-client automatically supports the digest authentication that that curl request is doing.

```
require 'rest-client'
response = RestClient::Request.execute(
            method: :post,
            url: 'https://api.kinghost.net/cliente',
            verify_ssl: false,
            user: "usuario",
            password: "senha",

            headers: {
              params: {
                clienteTipo: "I",
                clienteCPFCNPJ: "00112135045",
                clienteEmpresa: "NomeEmpresa",
                clienteNome: "meunome",
                clienteEmail: "email@dominio.com.br",
                clienteEmailCobranca: "emailcobranca@dominio.com.br",
                clienteSenhaPainel: "654321",
                clienteFone: "555100000000",
                clienteFax: "555100000001",
                clienteCEP: "44587421",
                clienteEndereco: "ruanome",
                clienteBairro: "meubairro",
                clienteCidade: "porto alegre",
                clienteEstado: "rs",
                clienteLimiteMapeamento: "1",
                clienteLimiteSubdominio: "2",
                clienteLimiteMysql: "3",
                clienteLimiteMssql: "1",
                clienteLimitePgsql: "1",
                clienteLimiteFirebird: "1",
                clienteLimiteFTPADD: "1",
                clienteUniBox: "on",
                clienteAcessoFTP: "on",
                clienteAcessoDownloadBackup: "on"
              }
            }
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

the wonders of curl :)

```
-k means unsecure (i.e don't check SSL)
--digest is the authentication type
-u name:password is the actual username and password
-X POST it's a post
-d "blah blah" blah blah is the payload
```

now onto ruby:
I would look at https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client or at https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty
It's just a matter of figuring out how to perform the post. The digest might be tricky but IIRC it can be some via Authorization header.